# Excel formula to extract multiple matching values

Tags: excel, formula

I'm looking for what I thought would be a pretty straightforward formula to compile a list of names based on a criterion. For example, I would have a list of 50 employee names in column A and then a "Y" or "N" next to each name in column B. I would then like to have another tab on the spreadsheet list the names of everyone with a "Y" value in column B. I dont want empty rows between the names in the list on the new tab (this is why I haven't had success with IF statements). I also would like to avoid manually filtering out blank rows.

Comment: Look at using a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your first sheet is Sheet1
on Sheet 2 on a1 enter:

```
   =IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH("Y",Sheet1!B:B,0))),"",INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH("Y",Sheet1!B:B,0)))
```

On a2 enter:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A:A,0)+1&":A50"),MATCH("Y",INDIRECT("Sheet1!B"&MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A:A,0)+1&":B50"),0))),"",(INDEX(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A:A,0)+1&":A50"),MATCH("Y",INDIRECT("Sheet1!B"&MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A:A,0)+1&":B50"),0))))
```

And just drag the 2nd formula down.

Note that I assumed your first sheet is with 50 Rows as you wrote, Otherwise  additional modifications needs to be made.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to include a short note mentioning that `IFNA` was introduced in Excel 2013.

Comment: @Jeeped, I will take your note and change my answer to use if(iserror) this way It wont be depended on new Excel version.

Comment: Actually, the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) seems to be an accepted standard (introduced in XL2007). That way, you won't have to double up your formula like `IF(ISERROR(...), "", ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you are looking for is quite complicated and requires cyclic calculation. For this reason, it is not advisable to use for long lists of several hundred or thousand 'names' but a list of 50 names should pose no discernible difficulties.

With the names in Sheet1's A2:A51, use this formula in the worksheet destined to receive the **Y** names.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$51, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$50)/(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$51="Y"), ROW(1:1))), "")
```

Fill down as necessary. Note that the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) is returning the *position within* A2:A51 with `ROW(1:50)`.

Retrieving the non **Y** names should be a simple matter of changing the primary condition to `(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$51="N")` or `(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$51<>"Y")`.

For pre XL2010 circumstances, this standard formula performs the same filtered retrieval.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Z!$A$2:$A$51, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$50)+(Z!$B$2:$B$51<>"Y")*1E+99, , ), ROW(1:1))), "")
```

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>